# This may be a basic question but I need to configure something but an error occurs

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

Before I start, I'm on windows and python 3.

I get this error when I try to run my code.

> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'configure'

The code is this. There is a few things I haven't included, that includes the files I made(which is soft coded) and the if statements(that because all of them are just copy and paste as they are similar to each other.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as box
import time
import random
import hashlib
import winsound
import webbrowser
import os

#I'll hardcode one file for the test
file.open("Song name12","w")
file.write("Artist: Ricky martin\n Song initals: L L V L")
file.close()
file.open("Song name12","r")
a12 = file.read()

def dialog1():
    global answer1
    global question
    global score
    score=0
    global counter
    counter=0
    global counter1
    counter1=3
    username=entry1.get()
    password = entry2.get()
    if (username == 'a' and  password == 'b'):
        box.showinfo('info','You may now enter the Music quiz')
        Quiz = Frame(window)
        Quiz.pack()
    def dialog2():
        global score
        score = 0
        global counter
        counter = 0
        condition = True
        final_answer = answer.get()
        answer.delete(0, END)
        if final_answer == ans2:
            counter = counter+1
            print("Correct")
            old = question2
            while old == question2:
                question = random.randint(1,30)

                if question2 == 12:
                    question.configure(text=a12)
                    question.pack()

    if question2 == 12:
        Text = Label(Quiz,text = 'What is this song?')
        Text.pack()
        question = Label(Quiz,text = a12)
        question.pack()
        answer = Entry(Quiz)
        answer.pack()
        Button1 = Button(Quiz, text='Check answer',command=dialog2)
        Button1.pack()
        ans2 = "Livin la vida loca"
window = Tk()
window.title('Music quiz')
window.geometry("300x125")
window.wm_iconbitmap('Favicon.ico')
loginframe = Frame(window)  #create an empty frame for login
loginframe.pack()  #put the empty frame into the window


Label1 = Label(loginframe,text = 'Username:')
Label1.pack()

entry1 = Entry(loginframe)
entry1.pack()

Label2 = Label(loginframe,text = 'Password: ')
Label2.pack()

entry2 = Entry(loginframe)
entry2.pack()

donebttn = Button(loginframe, text='Done',command=dialog1)#create a button to continue
donebttn.pack()  #display that button


mainloop()
```

Basically this code works up to the point of the while loop. then it gives me that error of into object, and I am still fairly new to gui and tkinter so I need help fixing my code to get rid of that error, if someone could add in how to thread my code to so it doesn't interfere with the main loop that would be great as I have never threaded anything like this before.
So there is two things I need, the first is fixing this error message then if someone could help me thread this. The main thing I need is for this to start working, and then if someone could help with threading it, that would be much obliged.

Comment: Unless you are running some kind of threading for your `dialog2` function you need to do something else other than use `while`. A `while` loop will freeze the mainloop and cause issues.

Comment: My whole code except the code to import and the main screen and all the other if statements which will not help

Comment: Please also include your imports and how your `dialog1` and `dialog2` functions are called.

Comment: So basically everything beside my if statements. OK

Comment: Well that's where we are at this point. If my answer below did not solve your issue then your issue is bigger than it looks.

Comment: Sorry if I ramble a bit, i'm a bit tired trying to find out how to do this.

Comment: So `Quiz2` does not exist in your code so you cannot destroy it. Also nothing in your code is calling `dialog2`. Also there is a lot missing in your code that `dialog2` is referencing. Where is `answer`, `ans2`, `question2` and `a12`? As it looks now your code will never reach the portion that causes the error as the while statement is never activated in this code. You must have missed something. Please update your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182743/discussion-between-tommy-lawrence-and-mike-smt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable "question" is a integer, you probably do something wrong higher in the code.

EDIT :

```
question = random.randint(1,30)
```

question is an interger type, so you can't use .configuration() methods.
if you want pick a random question to ask, you can declare a list and use `random.choice` methods

```
questions_list = [
    "my_first_question",
    "my_second_question",
    "ect..."
    ]

random.choice(questions_list)
```

Comment: Want me to displays whats above my if statements?

Comment: Yes, because you probably did something wrong with the declaration / assignment of your variable

Answer (score 2):

You have not shown enough code to reproduce your error however I can tell you based on your question you are trying to config an integer instead of what looks like originally was a button or label.

This line is causing your problem:

```
question = random.randint(1,30)
```

You are redefining your button/label as an integer and then trying to configure it.

Try to change this line `question = random.randint(1,30)` to something like `question_int = random.randint(1,30)` and you should get past this variable conflict.